# How to run exe file from python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess, os.system

I try to run a exe (In the background) from a specific path in my local python project, with the os.system libary.
I have managed to change folders like 'cd' Command, but i can't run the file.

This is for a python project running on Windows 64BIT, Python 3.5.3

the file.exe is at the "programs" dir.

```
import os
os.system("cd C:\Users\User\AppData\Windows\Start Menu\Programs")
subprocess.Popen("file.exe")
```

Error:

> {OSError}[WinError 193] %1 is not a valid Win32 application

I saw other posts about this issue but i couldn't resolve it.
Any ideas?

Comment: have you tried os.system("./file.exe")?

Comment: I might be wrong, but I think changing directory with an `os.system` call only changes the directory **for that call**. A shell is opened, the command is executed, and the shell is closed. Use `os.chdir` instead to change the scripts working directory.

Comment: @SyntaxVoid It worked for me. os.system() changed the path for the next commands as well

Comment: @Moshe, very strange. That is not how it acts on my machine, even if I run python as admin `os.getcwd(); os.system("cd Desktop"); os.getcwd()` will display the same directory and no change will happen. This happens regardless of me being in an interactive python shell, or running a .py file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem solved.
Thanks everyone, the issue was administrative privileges.. Started pycharm as administrator.
And like i said - i was able to see the file with os.listdir(), but when i try to run it, errors start to pop up.
I think the main issue is os.system() inherit current privileges from python proccess.

Answer (score 9):

Problem is that the `system` command doesn't work. It "works", but in a separate subprocess that exits right away. Current directory doesn't propagate up to the calling process (also, as you're not checking the return code, the command wouldn't fail, even with a non-existing directory. Note that it happens here, as the directory name has spaces in it and isn't quoted...).

You would have to use `os.chdir` for that, but you don't even need it.

If you want to run a command in a specific location, just pass the absolute path of the command (and since it's using string literals, always use `r` prefix to avoid that some `\t` or `\n` chars are interpreted as special characters...). For instance with python 3, with the command line provided there's an error (but okay in python 2...):

```
SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 5-6: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape
```

So always use raw prefix. Here's how I would rewrite that:

```
current_dir = r"C:\Users\User\AppData\Windows\Start Menu\Programs"
subprocess.Popen(os.path.join(current_dir,"file.exe"))
```

And if you really need that the current directory is the same as the exe, use `cwd` parameter. Also get the return value of `Popen` to be able to wait/poll/kill/whatever and get command exit code:

```
p = subprocess.Popen(os.path.join(current_dir,"file.exe"),cwd=current_dir)
# ...
return_code = p.wait()
```

As a side note, be aware that:

```
p = subprocess.Popen("file.exe",cwd=current_dir)
```

doesn't work, even if `file.exe` is in `current_dir` (unless you set `shell=True`, but it's better to avoid that too for security/portability reasons)

Note that `os.system` is deprecated for a lot of (good) reasons. Use `subprocess` module, *always*, and if there are argument, always with an argument *list* (not string), and avoid `shell=True` as much as possible.

Answer (score 2):

Can you see if this works

```
   import os 

    # change the current directory 
    # to specified directory 
    os.chdir(r"C:\Users\User\AppData\Windows\Start Menu\Programs") 
    subprocess.Popen("file.exe")
```

Comment: Not working, for some reason i cant reach the file from python. although i see it in os.listdir()