# python - SyntaxError: unexpected character after line continuation character

Tags: python, syntax, exec

> I made this very simple one line code that is only supposed to start Hearthstone, I get the error "SyntaxError: unexpected character after line continuation character", and don't know why.
> Here's the code:

`exec("C:\Program Files (x86)\Hearthstone\Hearthstone.exe")`

> Thanks in advance.

Comment: you are executing python code, `C:\Program Files (x86)\Hearthstone\Hearthstone.exe` is not a valid Python anything, try `import os` and then `os.system("C:\Program Files (x86)\Hearthstone\Hearthstone.exe")`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to run exe file from python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58697911/how-to-run-exe-file-from-python)

Comment: The problem is with the \ (escape sequence) Add r before the quotes.  r"C:\Program Files (x86)\Hearthstone\Hearthstone.exe"

Comment: @ozs That's an issue for when the correct function is being used to launch the executable.

Comment: use some path manipulation modules such as os.path https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html or npath?

Comment: @Matiiss that doesn't work, I don't think I'm supposed to use that with a path to an executable file, I get the error "'C:\Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file."

Comment: @ozs same error

Comment: @Zacarias_Barreto perhaps do `os.startfile('path/here')` or `os.system('start path/here')`

Comment: @cards I got the path, I just want to execute the file from the path

Comment: @Matiiss it worked! thank you so much

Comment: @Matiiss how do i like your comment or something? Im new to stackoverflow

Comment: @Zacarias_Barreto you don't, if it were an answer you could upvote or accept, comments ... you can't do anything (except reply and upvote (the upvote however is just to move the comment to top)) but it's just a small thing, more of a suggestion so just leave it as is, the question has probably been answered before so...

Answer (score 2):

In python `\` is a line continuation character and nothing can come after it on that line. To fix your problem use two backslashes `\\` or simply one forward slash `/`.